# Instatinating interface based object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having such a simple code:

```
interface int1 {
    aa: string,
    bb: number,
}

const obj1:int1 = {}  //#1

function fun(param_obj:int1) {  //#2
}
```

My question is why does the *compiler* shouts an error:

`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'int1': aa, bb`

on line *#1* an does NOT show an error on line *#2* since on both lines the new object is being created?

Comment: You don't create an object on line #2, you declare a function which accepts an object that will be created elswhere

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova Ok, got it. Thx:-)

Comment: No idea why it was downvoted, probably someone felt you didn't show enough research effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 line should still throw error because:

Since params aa and bb are not optional, as the error says object is missing properties defined in interface int1.

Depending what you intend to do, you can either make aa and bb optional with defining interface as following:

```
interface int1 {
  aa?: string,
  bb?: number
}
```

or use Partial [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

```
const obj1: Partial<int1> = {}
```

for line #2, is as mentioned already, you need to check where you pass in object.

Comment: I don't know, probably someone felt that error message is pretty self explanatory and thought that question on stackoverflow is obsolete.